# Deciphering cause of death?

Tags: palaeography, death-records, cause-of-death

I can't make this cause of death out:

[image: cause of death]

What might it be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1a Left Ventricular Failure
>   (b) Myocardial Degeneration
>   (c) Arterio sclerosis
>   Certified by C. J. C. Leggins MRCS

In other words, left-sided heart failure.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping (c) was "aliens" 

Answer (score 7):

The numbering a,b,c  indicates the way the conditions relate to the death, and should always be read "backwards".

So - Arterial sclerosis caused Myocardial degeneration, which in turn led to left ventricular failure, which was the actual cause of death.

Comment: Because there was no standardised way for physicians to certify the cause of death, the UK government employed (maybe still does employ) people to translate the terms used on death certificates into some kind of standard form so that they could be summarised in the national statistics. That's no help to genealogists, looking at an individual case .

Comment: There are very clear guidelines on acceptable causes of death, how they should be recorded, and the order in which they are placed (and numbered) and consequently shown on  on register entries and certificates. This is published by ONS and widely circulated to all doctors. Registrars are required to make sure the doctor has recorded the death in accordance with those rules.

Comment: There may be such guidelines now. But there certainly were not when I visited the GRO in 1973. And if you are interested in family history there were no clear guidelines from 1837.

Answer (score 3):

Left ventricular failure
Myocardial degeneration
Arterial sclerosis